# Using the verb call in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, subject-or-object

What would be the syntactic function of Intikas in the following sentence?

> They are called **Intikas** in their language.

It seems to me that in this case the verb *call* is behaving as a copulative verb, since Intikas can be identified with the subject *they* and, as a consequence, work as a sort of nominative predicate. But maybe this whole analysis is just misleading.

Comment: "To be called (or named)" is a phrase whose meaning is expressed by a single word in some languages (_heisst_ in German, I believe).

Comment: You haven't provided any analysis of the word *Intikas* in your question at all. Your question only considers the functions of *call* and *they*. Which word are you actually concerned with? (In this sentence, *Intikas* is a proper noun.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, I have said that in my opinion Intikas is functioning as a nominative predicate. I am concerned with the syntactic function of Intikas within the sentence.

Comment: Yes, "Intikas" is predicative complement, just as it is in the active "They call them Intikas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BillJ left a comment expressing support for your proposed analysis of "Intikas" as a **predicative complement**.

I would agree.

I don't think modern linguists would use the term "nominative predicate" because the traditional, prescriptive account of English "case", according to which the subject of a finite clause is in the "nominative case" and therefore a predicate ought to also be in the nominative case, is not considered to be an accurate model of how English grammar actually works (since speakers actually say things like "It's me", where "me" is predicative, but in the form traditionally identified as the "accusative case").